# Is there any way how logistic regression parameters can be preserved under a linear projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I have a logistic regression model and OLS estimation of its parameters $\hat{w}$:
$$y=\sigma(x^Tw + b)$$

Now, I would like to reduce the dimensionality of the space in which $x \in X$ lies by some linear projection (e.g. obtained by a low-rank SVD). Therefore I obtain a linear projection matrix $P$ that I want to apply to my data $D\subseteq X$ to get the reduced dimensionality dataset: 
$$D'=PD$$

Is there a general way how to project $\hat w$ so that I don't need to re-estimate the model?

(The reason why I'm reducing the dimensions is to lower the computational cost of the subsequent computations that use D in a quadratic form)